# How to have my VSTS Git Commit message show up in the discussion of a work item automatically?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Is there a way to have my VSTS Git Commit message to show up in the discussion of a work item automatically?

In the past when I used GitHub and JIRA, I had a connector that could pickup syntax from my commit messages and add them to specific JIRA ticket's discussions.

I would think there would be a way for VSTS to do this internally, seeing it is VSTS's Git Repo and Ticket system.

Comment: Did you try to use '#idWorkitem' in the commit message?

Comment: Yea, I used the following: "#139 Finished work, need to send to testing", unfortunately it didn't show up in the discussion for Work Item #139. I would also add that this commit was on the linked branch I had created for work item #139.

Answer (score 1):

No, the commit can only linked to a work item so far. It’s can’t be automatically show up in discussion area of a work it.

I posted an user voice [Associate git commit message with work item discussion](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20483854-associate-git-commit-message-with-work-item-discus), you can vote and follow up.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info, and yea I will be upvoting your entry.